# Looping with Firestore querying [Web/Javascript]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would I go about setting up a loop to query through my Firestore database structure? I don't believe I'm allowed to post pictures or links yet, so I'll try to give some path examples here. Note that there is a lot more to it than these examples.

```
Rating->Arrow->Arrow-Rating->(user ID)->(data fields)show_name, user_id, rating

Rating->Arrow->Arrow-Rating->(different user ID)->(data fields)show_name, user_id, rating
......



Rating->Flash->Flash-Rating->(user ID)->((data fields)show_name, user_id, rating<br />
......
```

To give a quick rundown of what this is all about, I'm trying to develop a mock site (with functionality) for a project, where I can display user created information (user info is created from a concurrently developed Android application) such as ratings.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get and display the average rating for each show, by getting each 'rating' field from each user in the respective "Rating" paths... i.e., getting a user rating from each show (Show-Rating->User ID/(data fields)), going to the next user from the same show, and then going to the next show and doing the same.

I'm just not entirely sure how to start going about this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a cloud function that listens for changes in the ratings node. Use OnUpdate listener
Store every movie rating in its own node, and only query that node for the rating 
This will reduce a lot of computation on the client side and will also be more efficient
Use [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) that describes a distributed counter